# Why is it wrong to think that `an exception is related to how frequently something happens`?

Tags: oop, exception

I met the following excerpt in the **CLR via C#** book:

> **Important** Many developers incorrectly believe that an exception is related to how frequently
>   something happens. For example, a developer designing a file *Read* method is likely to say the
>   following: “When reading from a file, you will eventually reach the end of its data. Since reaching the
>   end will always happen, I’ll design my *Read* method so that it reports the end by returning a special
>   value; I won’t have it throw an exception.” The problem with this statement is that it is being made by
>   the developer designing the *Read* method, not by the developer calling the *Read* method.
>
> When designing the *Read* method, it is impossible for the developer to know all of the possible
>   situations in which the method gets called. Therefore, the developer can’t possibly know how often the
>   caller of the *Read* method will attempt to read past the end of the file. In fact, since most files contain
>   structured data, attempting to read past the end of a file is something that rarely happens.

I can not understand two things which the excerpt (from my pov) was intended to explain. What does it mean that `an exception is related to how frequently something happens`? How is it possible to prove that it is not a correct way of thinking (I believe that a counterexample does the job of proving this, but still I do not understand the counterexample presented in the above excerpt)?

I do not understand the counterexample. Ok, let someone call a method which reads from a file many times after the end of the file was reached. Ok, let the method to report the end of the file all these times. I see no reasons for this to be worse than throwing an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author is saying a developer should not attempt to guess how often a branch of code will be executed by users, and should not decide whether to throw an exception from that branch based on their guess. In other words, it is incorrect to define an exception as, "something that doesn't happen very often."

The obvious reason for not making guesses is they may be wrong. A more fundamental reason is that exceptions are not necessarily infrequent, depending on the business domain. Consider an e-commerce site where users enter credit card numbers. Users will frequently enter their card numbers incorrectly. If we related exceptions to how frequently something happens, we might determine an incorrect CC number is *not* an exception, because it happens quite often.

Developers may be reluctant to throw exceptions. This often results in applications that "fail slow" because error conditions propagate beyond the point where they occur. Exceptions encourage an application to [fail fast](https://martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/failFast.pdf).

Related: [Avoid in-band error indicators](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/ERR52-J.+Avoid+in-band+error+indicators).

Comment: Oh. Fail fast is a useful concept to know about. The article you provided on that made my empirical knowledge on the matter structured.